# Is there any limit to the number of PPA's I can add to the system? Why?

Tags: ppa, software-sources

I came across a post which suggests:

> Do Not instruct people to add PPAs unless it is necessary

And one of the reason it has mentioned:

> There is a finite number of PPAs that a user can add.

Really?

Is there any limit to adding PPA's to the system? Why?

Also, on what factors do the limit depend?

Comment: Which post? When you quote something, link to it so that we can understand the context in which it was said.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of a number limit, but I do know that as you add more PPAs, you get more twisted and twisted dependency chains and PPAs can/will begin to conflict with each other.

You should only add a PPA if you really need/want what's in it.  I, for example, have the webupd8 PPA for ST and a couple of other things, X-Swat, and Kernel edgers.

If someone knows of a numerical hard limit, that would be good to know, but this is the reasoning on why I personally limit myself to a few PPAs.

*Edit*
Evidently [there is a hard limit](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195579) related to GPG keys, and it is being worked on.

Excerpt:
There is a neat way to squeeze couple of PPAs more through this keyhole of 40...
Look into /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d and You might find some pairs or triples of same size. Check them with diff and if they are same You can leave only one...

Comment: One person calls it a bug. Another a security feature. Adding that many PPA's seems asking for an invasion :P

Comment: I am accepting this as answer, since there is no _better_ alternative.  But I feel happy, if you find out the limit, if it exists (If you found, update), thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to augument the answer given already with example. 
Suppose you installed A on ppa X.  A depends on library libgit2 version 1 and won't work with 2. You install B from ppa Y and upgrades libgit2 to version 2 somehow. You have just screwed app A.

That is simple example but with interdependence web in Ubuntu packages you might end up with dead system. So be careful with PPAs