# Is there a maximum number of ppas that I can add?

Tags: ppa

I read this:

> There is a finite number of PPAs that a user can add (more accurately GPG Keys). If they don't need a PPA to solve the problem, don't make them use up one of their slots.

Is this true? I can't find any source. If this is true, what is the limit? I've seen the number 65k floated around but nothing concrete.

Comment: Where did you read it?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda on a stack exchange site which dislikes ppas. I can link, but it kind of detracts from the question. Here is is for context: http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/147/do-not-instruct-people-to-add-ppas-unless-it-is-necessary?cb=1

Comment: I think if you assumed it would take 1/10th of a second to perform an update scan on a PPA, and you have 65k PPA's you would be pretty upset about system performance...

Comment: @CharlesGreen Good point. However, is there a software limit rather than a user patience limit?

Comment: I honestly don't know, and did only a quick search to look for an answer.

Comment: why does this question sound familiar?! was this not asked the other day?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/697799/is-there-any-limit-to-add-ppas-to-the-system-why/697890 found it. asked 5 days ago.

Answer (score 2):

Technically there shouldn't be anymore, according to [this LP bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apt/+bug/1263540) a fix was released and "confirmed" for a bug in Apt/GnuPG as of 02/10/2015.

However, this bug still exists as of 15.04 (I can confirm, have had it affect both my vanilla Ubuntu 15.04 install and Ubuntu MATE 15.04 install), and thus you are, in effect, [limited to 40 PPAs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apt/+bug/1263540/comments/23).

*However*, there is, AFAIK, no configurable limit to PPAs.